# How do I set the a hide or visibility of a text box in SSRS using an expression?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm try to hide the Reset column in textbox like for an example if they score a 1 the Reset column should not appear but if they score a 2 then the Reset column should  appear
I try this expression =IIF(First(Fields!paroleHearingDecision.Value=2," Reset:______________________________________”) but it work what is the best way I need to write in visibility property of each tablix

[image]

Also, I start off with this expression in the begin =IIf(Parameters!paroleHearingDecisionID.Value=1
,"Ordered"
,"Denied"
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a tablix, the Visibility expression would be on the row. The actual property is Hidded so TRUE makes it hidden and FALSE will allow it to show.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!paroleHearingDecision.Value) = 2, True, False)
```

If there is no grouping, the FIRST is not needed.